# SQL database - PK and FK's

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

This is my code already, this was based off a template but mine doesn't work, comes up with errors about too many primary keys and missing keywords for the alter tables?

I'm not sure where to even start. If I try to insert any data then that just throws up errors too with missing expressions?

```
CREATE TABLE staff
(
   staff_id          INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   staff_name        VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   staff_surname     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   branch            VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
   jobrole           VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
   staff_contactno   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_staff PRIMARY KEY (staff_id)
);


CREATE TABLE property
(
   property_id           INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   owner_id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
   property_addressln1   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   property_addressln2   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   property_county       VARCHAR (26) NOT NULL,
   property_postcode     VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
   property_type         VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
   property_bedrooms     INTEGER NOT NULL,
   availability          VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
   valuation             INTEGER NOT NULL,
   fk1_owner_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
   fk2_staff_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
   fk3_client_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_property PRIMARY KEY (property_id, fk1_owner_id)
);

CREATE TABLE owner
(
   owner_id           INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   owner_name         VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   owner_surname      VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   owner_addressln1   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   owner_addressln2   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   owner_county       VARCHAR (26) NOT NULL,
   owner_postcode     VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
   owner_contactno    INTEGER NOT NULL,
   owner_email        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_owner PRIMARY KEY (owner_id)
);

CREATE TABLE client
(
   client_id          INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   client_name        VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   client_surname     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   client_contactno   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   client_email       VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_client PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);

ALTER TABLE property ADD CONSTRAINT fk1_property_to_owner FOREIGN KEY(fk1_owner_id) REFERENCES owner(owner_id) ON DELETE restrict on update cascade;



ALTER TABLE property ADD CONSTRAINT fk2_property_to_staff FOREIGN KEY(fk2_staff_id) REFERENCES staff(staff_id) ON DELETE restrict on update cascade;


ALTER TABLE property ADD CONSTRAINT
fk3_property_to_client FOREIGN KEY(fk3_client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE restrict on update cascade;
```

Answer (score 1):

A table can have only one Primary key. You try to create 2

First: `Staff_id    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,`
second: `CONSTRAINT  pk_STAFF PRIMARY KEY (Staff_id)`

Of course with the same column, but this is not checked by the dbms

remove the Primary key after the first line of each table and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE staff
(
   staff_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
   staff_name        VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   staff_surname     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   branch            VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
   jobrole           VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
   staff_contactno   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "STAFF".
   -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
   CONSTRAINT pk_staff PRIMARY KEY (staff_id)
);
```

Next thing is that `ON DELETE RESTRICT` is not supported by ORACLE

The last thing is, that a Primary key should not Change, so `on update` makes no sence

Answer (score 1):

- you may only define a *PRIMARY KEY* constraint once for each table
- if you defined a *PRIMARY KEY*, it would already has *NOT NULL*
  constraint and no need to mention more.

So, Let's consider the table `staff`

( the following warning is also for the rest of the other *CREATE TABLE* statements )

*Create* that as :

```
CREATE TABLE staff
(
   staff_id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   staff_name        VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   staff_surname     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   branch            VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
   jobrole           VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
   staff_contactno   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

or as :

```
CREATE TABLE staff
(
   staff_id          INTEGER,
   staff_name        VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   staff_surname     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   branch            VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
   jobrole           VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
   staff_contactno   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_staff PRIMARY KEY (staff_id)   
);
```

- There's no option called `ON UPDATE` for creating a `FOREIGN KEY` in
  *Oracle*.
- Yes, there's option called `ON DELETE` for creating a `FOREIGN KEY` in
  *Oracle*

  ***as*** `ON DELETE CASCADE` *or* `ON DELETE SET NULL` ***but*** ***NOT*** `ON DELETE RESTRICT`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF(

Staff_id    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Staff_name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Staff_surname   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Branch  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
JobRole VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Staff_contactno INTEGER NOT NULL,
-- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "STAFF".
-- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
CONSTRAINT  pk_STAFF PRIMARY KEY (Staff_id)
);
```

You are already described Staff_id as primary key and you should not add constraint into query. Correct queries are

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF(

Staff_id    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Staff_name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Staff_surname   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Branch  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
JobRole VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Staff_contactno INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF(

Staff_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
Staff_name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Staff_surname   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Branch  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
JobRole VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Staff_contactno INTEGER NOT NULL,
-- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "STAFF".
-- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
CONSTRAINT  pk_STAFF PRIMARY KEY (Staff_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

About the `CREATE TABLE`, you can not enforce the PK both inline and as a constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF
(
    Staff_id                                INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Staff_name                              VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Staff_surname                           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Branch                                  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    JobRole                                 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Staff_contactno                         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "STAFF".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT pk_STAFF PRIMARY KEY(Staff_id)
);

CREATE TABLE PROPERTY
(
    Property_id                             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Owner_id                                INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Property_addressLn1                     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Property_addressLn2                     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Property_county                         VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
    Property_postcode                       VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    Property_type                           VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Property_bedrooms                       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Availability                            VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Valuation                               INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk1_Owner_id                            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk2_Staff_id                            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    fk3_Client_id                           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "PROPERTY".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT pk_PROPERTY PRIMARY KEY(Property_id, fk1_Owner_id)
);

CREATE TABLE OWNER
(
    Owner_id                                INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Owner_name                              VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Owner_surname                           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Owner_addressLn1                        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Owner_addressLn2                        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Owner_county                            VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
    Owner_postcode                          VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    Owner_contactno                         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Owner_email                             VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "OWNER".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT pk_OWNER PRIMARY KEY(Owner_id)
);

CREATE TABLE CLIENT
(
    Client_id                               INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Client_name                             VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Client_surname                          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Client_contactno                        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Client_email                            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "CLIENT".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT pk_CLIENT PRIMARY KEY(Client_id)
);
```

About the `ALTER`, Oracle does not support whet you're trying to do, see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined column level and table level primary key for same table. That's why your getting too many primary key error

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE staff
(
   staff_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
   staff_name        VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   staff_surname     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   branch            VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
   jobrole           VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
   staff_contactno   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_staff PRIMARY KEY (staff_id)
);

CREATE TABLE owner
(
   owner_id           INTEGER NOT NULL,
   owner_name         VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   owner_surname      VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   owner_addressln1   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   owner_addressln2   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   owner_county       VARCHAR (26) NOT NULL,
   owner_postcode     VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
   owner_contactno    INTEGER NOT NULL,
   owner_email        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_owner PRIMARY KEY (owner_id)
);

CREATE TABLE client
(
   client_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
   client_name        VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   client_surname     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
   client_contactno   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   client_email       VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_client PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);

CREATE TABLE property
(
   property_id           INTEGER NOT NULL,
   owner_id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
   property_addressln1   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   property_addressln2   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   property_county       VARCHAR (26) NOT NULL,
   property_postcode     VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
   property_type         VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
   property_bedrooms     INTEGER NOT NULL,
   availability          VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,   
   valuation             INTEGER NOT NULL,   
   fk1_owner_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
   fk2_staff_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
   fk3_client_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT pk_property PRIMARY KEY (property_id, fk1_owner_id),
   CONSTRAINT fk1_property_to_owner FOREIGN KEY(fk1_owner_id) REFERENCES owner(owner_id) ON DELETE restrict on update cascade,
   CONSTRAINT fk2_property_to_staff FOREIGN KEY(fk2_staff_id) REFERENCES staff(staff_id) ON DELETE restrict on update cascade,
   CONSTRAINT fk3_property_to_client FOREIGN KEY(fk3_client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE restrict on update cascade
);
```

Note: I am not sure purpose of owner_id and fk1_owner_id columns in property table. It seems duplicate column. If its duplicate then please remove owner_id column from property table